In Blender 3.3, how do I make the arrow keys move in increments with each press instead of having to hold the key
In edit mode, when I select a vertex or an edge, and press "G" followed by an arrow key, nothing happens immediately. I have to hold down the arrow key, and after half a second, the vertex starts to move. This process feels slow and imprecise.
I want to press an arrow key once and have the vertex move one increment (I have snap to grid activated). If I press the arrow key four times quickly, I want the vertex to move four increments and etc. How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

To be honest I didn't even know that you could move an edge or vertex with the arrow key! I've certainly never heard of anyone modeling that way. You usually turn on Snap > Increment, hit G and move the mouse in the direction you want.

After a month I'm just going to assume that is just not possible for some reason.

I suspect that no-one has ever wanted that facility so has never asked for it. You could try suggesting it on Right-click Select but I doubt many people there are using Blender 3.3 now so it's unlikely you'll get any interest.
